# How can I get lint warnings when I've forgotten to require a package?

Tags: flycheck, byte-compilation

Flycheck has a brilliant ability to warn about when I'm using a function `foo-bar` but have forgotten to add `(require 'foo)` at the top of my file.

However, it's inconsistent. It doesn't always warn for functions from some packages, even if the function is not autoloaded. How can I make Emacs warn me about these?

```
;; This produces a warning
;; "the function `which-function' is not known to be defined."
(defun which-func-not-required ()
  (which-function))

;; This produces no warning.
(defun cl-not-required (x)
  (cl-copy-list x))

;; This produces no warning either.
(defun byte-comp-not-required (f)
  (byte-compile-top-level f))

;; end
```

(inspired by [this PR](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/names/pull/1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will **never** get warnings about functions from `bytecomp.el` being undefined during byte-compilation, for a very obvious reason:

`bytecomp.el` **implements** the byte compiler, so it is naturally loaded and all functions therein defined during byte-compilation, whether the compiled files loads it or not.  This also affects all libraries loaded by `bytecomp.el`, notably `macroexp`.

There is **nothing** that you or Flycheck (or, for that matter, any Emacs Lisp code) could do about this.  It is a **fundamental flaw** in Emacs:  Libraries are compiled within the running Emacs session, and thus inherit the entire environment (including all definitions) of this session.

You **should** get warnings about undefined functions from `cl-lib`, though.  If you don't, you do not compile in a clean session.  Check your settings.

Comment: "Check your settings" aha, turns out my `(setq-default flycheck-emacs-lisp-initialize-packages t)` caused this behaviour. I'll look at cask instead.

Comment: "There is nothing [..] any Emacs Lisp code could do about this" the byte compiler is just elisp, I suppose one could write a standalone, pure elisp lint and run it in a clean environment. It'd be a huge task though.